# Spring cannot create define a bean of abstract class in the configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, lombok

```
public abstract class AbstractMapper<T> implements Function<SomeProducts, T> {

private final ABC abc;
private final XYZ xyz;

constructor()

some abstract methods
```

i have two implementations of this abstract class

```
@Component
public class ProductDTOMapper extends AbstractMapper<Product> {

    constructor()

    @Override
    public Product apply(final SomeProducts products) {
        return Product.builder()
            .id()
            .build();
    }
```

The second implementation of the abstract class

```
@Component
    public class CustomerDTOMapper extends AbstractMapper<CustomerDocument> {
    
        constructor()
    
        @Override
        public CustomerDocument apply(final SomeProducts products) {
            return CustomerDocument.builder()
                .id()
                .build();
        }
```

I build the CustomerDocument and Product with lombok:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Type("typeA")
public class CustomerDocument {

some attributes

}
```

The second builder-class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Type("typeB")
public class Product {

some attributes

}
```

In my controller i have the instances of the two mapper:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class ZController {

    private final AbstractMapper<Product> productDTOMapper;
    private final AbstractMapper<CustomerDocument> customerDTOMapper;
```

When i start the application, i get this error:

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in ZController required a bean of type 'x.y.z.rest.mapper.AbstractMapper' that could not be found.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zController' defined in file [/path/to/controller/rest/controller/ZController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'x.y.z.rest.mapper.AbstractMapper<rest.dto.product.CustomerDocument>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the concrete Java class name as the field types in the controller; i.e. private final CustomerDTOMapper customerDTOMapper;

Answer (score 4):

have a look to this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class ZController {

    private final ProductDTOMapper productDTOMapper;
    private final CustomerDTOMapper customerDTOMapper;
```

if you want to type with super class
try to use field dependency injection instead of constructor DI, and use a mix of `@Qualifier` and `@Autowired` annotations.

regards,